# Return BadRequest with null required property in model .net core web api

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, modelstate

So, I have my controller with a create method in it:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ConversionsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IGenericService<Conversion> _conversionService;
    public ConversionsController(IGenericService<Conversion> conversionService) => _conversionService = conversionService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new conversion
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="conversion">The conversion</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Conversion), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(ConversionViewModel conversion)
    {
        if (conversion == null) return BadRequest();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var request = ModelFactory.Create(conversion);

        _conversionService.Create(request);
        await _conversionService.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Created(nameof(Get), new Sxp.Web.ActionResult<Conversion>(request, string.Format(Resources.EntityCreated, "conversion")));
    }
}
```

As you can see, if there is no model it will return a bad request (which works).

But the next line stating `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` never works. It always returns valid even with a required property at *null*.

I have written a test, which always fails:

```
[Test]
public async Task ReturnBadRequestIfNullRequiredProperty()
{
    // Assemble
    var services = ConversionsControllerContext.GivenServices();
    var controller = services.WhenCreateController();

    // Act
    var actionResult = await controller.CreateAsync(new ConversionViewModel());
    var badRequestResult = actionResult as BadRequestResult;

    // Assert
    badRequestResult.Should().NotBeNull();
    badRequestResult?.StatusCode.Should().Be(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
}
```

As you can see here, I just pass a `CategoryViewModel` with no properties set at all, but it fails.

The view model looks like this:

```
public class ConversionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RangeErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public int FeedId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources)), StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources)), StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public string FieldName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources)), StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public string Expression { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public MathOperator MathOperator { get; set; }
    public FilterOperator FilterOperator { get; set; }
}
```

The only other thing I can think of, is I disabled automatic state validation:

```
.ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => { options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; });
```

Which I thought allowed me to handle it within the controller.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a unit test and not an end to end integration test so there are certain framework concerns that are not running when the test is exercised.

Those data annotation attributes are metadata that is only recognized by the framework at run time and not during an isolated unit test as they are actually read by the model binder when the application is running.

If the intention was to have the framework validate the model then an integration test is needed.

Reference [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests)

Otherwise the subject under test (the controller) has to have its `ModelState` updated manually when arranging the test so that it behaves as expected when being exercised.

An invalid model state is tested by adding errors using `AddModelError` as shown in the test below:

```
[Test]
public async Task ReturnBadRequestIfNullRequiredProperty() {
    // Arrange / Assemble
    var services = ConversionsControllerContext.GivenServices();
    var controller = services.WhenCreateController();
    controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Name","Name required"); //<-- Invalidate model state
    //...other desired errors.

    // Act
    var actionResult = await controller.CreateAsync(new ConversionViewModel());
    var badRequestResult = actionResult as BadRequestResult;

    // Assert
    badRequestResult.Should().NotBeNull();
    badRequestResult?.StatusCode.Should().Be(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
}
```

Reference [Test controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `services.AddMvcCore` instead of `services.AddMvc` then add

```
services.AddDataAnnotations();
```

to Startup.ConfigureServices method